# how to reduce the url length?

Tags: html, jsp

I am passing variables in `href` and some variables contain a lot of values. eg: features of a cell phone

jsp code :

```
<%
    out.println("<a href='itemdetails.jsp?features="+p.getFeatures() +"&price="+p.getPrice()+"&pname="+p.getPname()+"&img="+p.getImg()+"'><div style='display: inline-block; background: url("+p.getImg()+"); height: 200px; width: 200px;'></div></a>"); 
%>
```

so that url becomes very long, is there any other method I can pass these variables. by using `session`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Replace  'a'  tag with    "input type='submit'"
   if needed, make button look like 'a' tag
2. Enclose the above input element into a form element with 'method as POST'
3. Have an invisible ' textarea name as 'myquerystring1' ' field with name tag, set your long url query string (i.e;. data after itemdetails.jsp) to textarea.
4. When user clicks the submit button, the textarea contents are posted to itemdetails.jsp, with name myquerystring1, that you can catch them here, do whatever you want.

Hope that helps, best of luck.

See this link for Textarea example
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp
See this link on how to use POST in jsp.
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/Getsubmitbuttonvalue.htm
See this link more on POST:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method_post